# How do you delete a node in networkx?

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I have a dataset that I'm uploading as a graph for various timeframes and trying to figure relationships between them.

I want to delete all the nodes that do not have edges but I'm not sure the command to remove or delete nodes. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','D'),('C','D')])
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
G.remove_node('B')
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To remove multiple nodes, there is also the [Graph.remove_nodes_from()](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.graph.html#adding-and-removing-nodes-and-edges) method.

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.graph.html#adding-and-removing-nodes-and-edges) covers it.

> Graph.remove_node(n): Remove node n.
>
> Graph.remove_nodes_from(nodes): Remove multiple nodes.

For example:

```
In : G=networkx.Graph()

In : G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])

In : G.nodes()
Out: [1, 2, 3]

In : G.remove_node(2)

In : G.nodes()
Out: [1, 3]
```